# Is it possible to set a button to onPause and onResume in Android?

Tags: java, android, toggle, auto, pause

I am working on a music app. Right now if you close the app temporaly all sound stop, and then upon return they autostart.
This is good for some users but if you use the multiscreen stuff in Android, aka 2 apps simultaneously, it sucks.

Is it possible to make a button in one of the fragments that let's the user turn on and off this feature?

```
@Override
     public void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       sp.autoPause();
  }
 @Override
     public void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       sp.autoResume();
   }
```

Sp is a soundpool.

Comment: what feature you want to turn on/off on button click? Could you please elaborate more.

Comment: With the click of a toggle button I want to turn off the autopause and autoresume features. So the user could decide if the needs that or not.